# Why my function middleContainer is undefine - JS modules

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web, file-not-found

I tested my JS code with Node and the ***import*** keyword gets flagged. I have read and watch videos on how to import vars,etc from other JS files.

I believe my syntax is correct, but I do not understand why it does not work properly.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>JAPC</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8"/>

        <!-- CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/page_structure.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/navstack_structure.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./CSS/jpdc_structure.css">
        <link rel="icon" href="./Images/Page_Imgs/favicon-16x16.png">

        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="module" src="./JS/page_structure.js"> </script>

    </head>

    <body onload="middleContainer()">
        <div> <!--DIV 1-->
            <div id="top_container">
                <!--DIV 1.1 | Header-->
                <h1>Header</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- --------------------- -->
            <div id="middle_container">
                <!--DIV 1.2 | Body-->
            </div>
            <!-- --------------------- -->
            <div id="bottom_container">
                <h1>Footer</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Here is my JS code:**

```
/*
    Page Structure
*/
import { top_container_config, middle_container_config, bottom_container_config} from './page_structure_config.js';

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function createDOMelement(element_, attributues_){
  var elem_ = document.createElement(element_);
  var k;
    for (k in attributues_){
      elem_.setAttribute(k,attributues_[k]);
  }
  return elem_;
}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function topConainter(){
  var _container = "top_container";

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function middleContainer(){
  var _container_ID = "middle_container";
  var _columns = [];
  var _navVar;
  var _nv_items =[];

  //Columns
  for(var col = 0; col < middle_container_config.mc_columns.num; col++){
    _columns.push(createDOMelement("div",middle_container_config.mc_columns._DOM_));
  }

  //My Nav Var
  _navVar =  createDOMelement("div", middle_container_config.nav_stack._DOM_);

  //Inside my Nav Var
  for(var nv_i = 0; nv_i < middle_container_config.nav_stack_items.num; nv_i++){
    _nv_items.push(createDOMelement("div",middle_container_config.nav_stack_items._DOM_));
  }


  //JOIN ALL ELEMENT  - Inside OUt
  for (var a =0; a<_nv_items.length; a++){
    _navVar.appendChild(_nv_items[a]);
  }

  //Append NavVar to first column of the middle_container
  _columns[0].appendChild(_navVar);

  //add to DOM
  for(var b=0; b<_columns.length; b++){
    document.getElementById(_container_ID).appendChild(_columns[b]);
  }

  console.log(document.getElementById(_container_ID));

}

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function bottomContainer(){
  var _container = "bottom_container";

}
```

**Here is picture of my Node output:**

I run my node command as the following:

> node page_structure.js

[image]

Comment: just curious, why do you think `npm run sourceFile.js` would get it working?

Comment: @Tsuna, interesting I had the idea that "npm run" would execute my JS code but as Petr below mentions node is the command that does it. Thank you. I would edit the question with the proper command.

Comment: guess you mixed up `npm` with `node` haha.  It's good that you don't get them mixed up

Comment: Your code is not does not reflect a code for node application but rather reflect a code for web application. I think what you are looking for is to import `page_structure.js` in your `index.html`. You don't need to run node application for frontend script.

Comment: @DakotaJang, I understand, however I though node would parse my JS file and let me know of any errors like the import keyword. Also, I'm calling my JS file in my HTML file in the <script> tag.

Comment: Your `onload=middleContainer()` will not work because middleContainer is defined in a module and not in global scope. Please try if `window.middleContainer = ...` works for you instead of `function middleContainer(){...}`.

Comment: @DakotaJang, I see. Question, I'm importing a JS object from another file, as you can see in line 1 of my JS file. I read that I had to put "type = module" in order for exports/imports to work in JS in my HTML file. So is this what I'm doing wrong? I'm asking because I've defined functions the way I did in this file and they have worked properly when calling them as how I did in the HTML.

Comment: @Andy To import modules you have to use `type = module`. The functions and variables defined in the module script is only defined in that module scope. When you use `onload=middleContainer()`, it is looking for middleContainer defined in global scope (i.e. `window.middleContainer`), which you don't have. So, yes, `type = module` is messing you up, but you need it for `import` keyword. You should have noticed this in your browser's console. Please check the console errors and add it to the post if it seems relevant next time.

Comment: @DakotaJang, the conosle only reports that the function "middleContainer()" is not define. Basically, all I want to to is import a JS object into my file and be able to use it in the web page I'm testing. How can I fix this? Thank you.

Comment: @Andy Seems like your question is "why is `middleContainer` undefined?". Please rephrase your question, and include the console error message in the question as that would have helped save a lot of time for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your `onload` listener is not aware of `middleContainer` function because `middleContainer` is not defined on global scope.

One of the option is to just define the function on global scope.

```js
// in page_structure.js
// middleContainer defined on module scope
function middleContainer(){
  var _container_ID = "middle_container";
  ...
}
// middleContainer defined global scope
window.middleContainer = middleContainer;
```

Then `<body onload="middleContainer()">` should no longer complain about `middleContainer` being undefined and should run the `middleContainer` function.

Another option is to add the `onload` event listener to your module. Instead you can remove the `onload` attribute on the `<body>` tag and defined the `onload` event as follows

```js
// in page_structure.js
function middleContainer(){
  var _container_ID = "middle_container";
  ...
}
// define the listener with your module scoped function to a global event listener
window.onload = middleContainer;
```

Comment: Dakota, your answer works perfectly. I will however read a bit more on in JS scoping. It's a bit tangled how the language works. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5):

Npm run is used to run a command defined in package.json.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/run-script

You can run your script with `node page_structure.js`

Comment: Petr, than you, Yes it's node not npm. My bad. I would edit the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding how `npm` and `npm run` works.  package.json is not a file that is used by the code YOU wrote anywhere, it is used by NPM to manage/run projects. Read more here: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

If you run the command `npm init` a package.json file will be created for you. You can then add a run script inside so it looks something like:

```
{
     "name" : "Some Name",
     "version" : "1.0.0",
     "scripts": {
         "start": "node page_structure.js",
         "other script": "some other bash command"
     }
}
```

Now there is a package.json with a script called "start" defined. `npm run start` will now execute the command `node page_structure.js` which should run your file.